# Register a value after a given date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a financial sheet and I want to record my monthly final balance each month but automatically. This is my sheet:

[image: This is the sheet]

I tried this code:

```
Public Sub DATA()

If Today > 31 / 3 / 2021 Then
Range("L10").Value = Range("I16").Value
Else
End If

End Sub
```

The Idea is to copy/paste a value from one cell to another only in the last day of the month and keep this value there forever. For example:

at 31/03/2021, I would run the macro and it would copy/paste the final balance of this month to the "Março" cell in the right, and this value would stay there.

I'm new to VBA so, can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `If date() > cdate("2021-03-31") Then`

Comment: The date would need to be in EN-US format or a universal format like my comment above

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, maybe something like `If Date = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0) Then` to test if the current date is the end of the month.

Comment: @ScottCraner Is there a way to make the the year and the day always the same and set only the month as the current month?

Comment: @BigBen what I'm trying to do is to copy the value of an specific cell to another one, only when the day is the last of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

> what I'm trying to do is to copy the value of an specific cell to another one, only when the day is the last of the month.

Use [`WorksheetFunction.EoMonth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.eomonth) with `0` as the second argument:

```
If Date = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0) Then
    Range("L10").Value = Range("I16").Value
End If
```